# Package MS Flow with SPFx app

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have created an SPFx app with below artifacts

1. A custom list
2. A content Type
3. Site Columns
4. MS Flows on custom list.

i want to package my MS Flows along with SPFX app.
But i don't have any clue how to package the flow with app.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that provisioning MS Flows via SPFX is supported yet or if it will ever be.
According to this link from MS (https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/toolchain/provision-sharepoint-assets) the assets you can provision in SPFX are:

- Fields
- Content Types
- List Instances
- List Instances with custom schema

Comment: Thanks nikolaj.
actually i want to develop apps using spfx that i can provide as single app package. containing list creation , site columns creation , content types creation etc along with the required workflows/MS Flows. 
if i cannot package the workflow/flows with app package (.sppkg or .app in add-in model)  the app can not be provided as a single package. 

i want to create apps that end user will just install in sharepoint and start to use.